# Is there a way to add ‘separators’ to the menubar?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar, ui

Does anyone know of a tiny pseudo-app that adds fake menubar widgets, ones that take effectively no resources and have no icon, so I can ‘space out’ my menubar?

> (I ask because I use [Bartender.app](https://macbartender.com), and have ~30 menubar apps; they get pretty hard to skim over all in one line :P)

Answer (score 2):

I've also spent countless hours searching for a way to achieve this. Recently I found a paid app on the App Store ($3.99) called infinite menu bar that claimed it could add separators to the menubar. I purchased it (had zero stars on the App Store so I was a little worried) but it works great! It allows you to make small, medium, & large separators.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/infinite-menu-bar/id1439179659?mt=12